# when exactly is an object created in java

Tags: java, overriding

Given the below code snippet:

```
class SuperClass {
    SuperClass () {
        foo();
    }

    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("In SuperClass foo");
    }
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    private String str;
    SubClass() {
        str = "SubClass";
    }

    public void foo () {
        System.out.println("In SubClass foo value " + str.toLowerCase());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SuperClass ref = new SubClass();
        ref.foo();
    }
}
```

This codes throws NPE because in the SuperClass constructor when foo() is invoked its actually calling the SubClass foo() and throws NPE. I want to understand when exactly is the SubClass object created here since we are still in the process of initializing the member variables of the SubClass in its constructor then why there is an overriding happening here?

Comment: It will not throw a NPE. Also, never call a overridable method from the constructor.

Comment: It will not throw NPE, but it will call the SuperClass constructor but won't call overridden method in SuperClass as you assign SubClass reference to SuperClass object.

Comment: I'd really like to know which line is getting the NPE. The only pointer (that is used) is ref, and that's only after your problem. If a non-static method is called, it has to be called from an object, else it throws a static context error, not an NPE. Also, how is SuperClass's constructor called when there isn't even a super()?

Comment: what is your java file name here??

Comment: The NPE is thrown in SubClass foo() when we try to print the string in lowercase.

Comment: Your original post did not contain that. Yes, in that case, `str` is not initialized

Comment: How about you just post the whole thing, and then we can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialise `Subclass`, the `Superclass` constructor is called first. The superclass (more general) needs to be constructed before the subclass (more specific). Makes sense, right?

Now, in the superclass's constructor, `foo` is called. Guess *which* `foo` is called? The subclass's `foo`! This is because you are creating a `Subclass` object, so every instance method you call is going to invoke the subclass's implementation, due to [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

So the subclass's `foo` is called and it tries to print `str.toLowerCase()`. Note that since the subclass's constructor has not been called yet, `str` is not initialised so has the initial value of `nil`, throwing a `NullPointerException`.

If the subclass's `foo` method ran successfully, then the superclass's constructor would have returned, and the subclass's constructor would finally have been called.

The lesson of the day: **Don't call non-final methods in a non-final class's constructor.**

Comment: What I am not understanding is how come the SubClass objected is created at the point where foo() is called from SuperClass contructor since its still in the process of initializing the member variables.

Comment: @Abhilash28Abhi The subclass object is not fully created. That's why you shouldn't call `foo` in the superclass constructor. The subclass `foo` is called not because the subclass object has been fully created, but because `this` refers to, at runtime, an instance of the subclass. `this.foo` refers to the `foo` implementation of the subclass.

Comment: @Abhilash28Abhi If you still don't understand, just think that objects are created even before any of your constructors are run. Is it easier to understand that way?

Comment: Yes, this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As Link : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-67/

**In Java, constructor of base class with no argument gets automatically called in derived class constructor.**

when ref is created then it have address : SubClass@c2e1f26 . It is SubClass.
So. When in SuperClass() construction call foo then it search foo() in SubClass and perform it.

**Update follow question** 
 - We should remember.SuperClass() constructor is call first SubClass() contructor. So when property str don't init.

Answer (score 0):

```
it will first call the subclass constructor then subclass to the superclass and then superclass to the object and the execution returns to the superclass then it will start printing.
the first statement will print
```

> **In SuperClass foo**
>
> **In SubClass foo value subclass**

```
but since the str is not followed up then it will obviously throw the null pointer exception.
```