# When is object created in Java?

Tags: java

I can't believe it wasn't asked already, it sounds very basic, but I searched on SO and haven't found such a question (it's not [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50383537/23434786) since it's actually about the order of invoked constructors)

**When** is an object created in Java (from the GC's standpoint)?

I didn't give it much thought at first. "At least, no sooner than the constructor finishes execution," I figured. Then I discovered that Mockito uses some esoteric native technology to bypass constructors at all

And then I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74554261/why-do-java-finalizers-have-security-problems) about finalizers. I checked and confirm that this code

```java
public class FinalizerAttackExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
      try {
          new MaliciousSubclass();
      } catch(SecurityException ex) {
          System.out.println("wouldn't get hands on a ResourceClass instance");
      }
      System.gc();
      Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

    static class ResourceClass {
        ResourceClass() {
            if(!checkCaller()) throw new SecurityException();
        }
        public void criticalAction() {
            System.out.println("ResourceClass.criticalAction()");
        }
    }

    /** For our demonstration, all callers are invalid */
    static boolean checkCaller() {
        return false;
    }

    static class MaliciousSubclass extends ResourceClass {
        @Override
        protected void finalize() {
            System.out.println("see, I got hands on " + this);
            criticalAction();
        }
    }
}
```

*indeed* produces this output (the hash may be different)

```
wouldn't get hands on a ResourceClass instance
see, I got hands on FinalizerAttackExample$MaliciousSubclass@7ad74083
ResourceClass.criticalAction()
```

Which begs the question: what object was `finalize()` invoked on if the constructor never successfully completed? Is a Java object created in an imaginary "finally" block of a constructor? Is it created beforehand? Here's what the specification says

> A new class instance is explicitly created when evaluation of a class instance creation expression (§15.9) causes a class to be instantiated.
>
> [JLS, §12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5)

It doesn't clear things up at all

If it happens to be JVM-specific (which it shouldn't be), let's assume we're running our code on Hotspot

Comment: Given that a constructor will be performing operations on an object (setting its fields for instance) clearly the object exists before the constructor begins to execute, and so will be finalised whether the constructor completes successfully or not.

Comment: Right, basically, the `new` command allocates memory needed, then the constructors are called in order down the hierarchy, starting with `Object` (which as far as I know does nothing).  The object is not "completely constructed" until the last constructor is called, but the memory locations exist and will be initialized (if needed) before your constructor is called.

Comment: Also, when you call `new MyClass()`, the first object created is the class object, `Class<MyClass>` which itself needs to be initialized, then the memory is allocated for the instance which is also initialized (constructed).  If we're being picky.

Comment: @markspace do you mean a `MyClass` object is created when `new MyClass` is evaluated but before anything else happens (including `super()`s, initialziers)?

Comment: I mean memory is allocated.  Technically it isn't a proper object until all memory is initialized by its constructors (for example, you might impose the constraint on the class Animals that all Animals have a name (string).  If the constructor doesn't run, then `name` might actually be `null`, violating the constraint.  The memory is allocated, but the constraints aren't fulfilled, so it's not really a proper object yet.)

Comment: Creation of an object is a process ... not an event.

Comment: Finalizers are going to be dropped from the Java language; https://openjdk.org/jeps/421.  Building new code that uses / depends on them in 2024 is a bad idea.  And understanding how to do it safely from untrusted code is a waste of time, since Java has already dropped the security sandbox mechanisms.  Such things *should* be of historical interest only.

Comment: **HINT**: [JLS-8.8.9. Default Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9) means there was a `super()` call **very** early in the object creation life-cycle. Even if your constructor didn't complete, the prototypical one likely did. And that is subject to garbage collection.

Comment: @StephenC but if you can invoke methods on it, like `finalize()`, it's already there, isn't it?

Comment: Why can't you guys just write an answer? We need to save it from the vacuum, if nothing else

Comment: Well yea ... it is there.  But until the constructors have all (successfully) completed it isn't a full object.  As has already been explained, the object kind of exists as soon as the memory has been allocated.

Comment: Because this is boring ... and you are not paying me enough :-)   (And it probably has been asked and answered before ... and I'm too lazy to find the Q&A for you.)

Comment: The answer is "whenever the JVM wants to, provided the outcome is the same"

Comment: (Or more precisely ... provided that it conforms to the JLS.  The JLS doesn't guarantee that the "outcome" is the same if you poke around under the hood in certain ways.  And there are areas where the JLS doesn't give a definite answer ... and it is "implementation dependent"; e.g. in the JMM ... where you only get guaranteed visibility behavior if your code follows certain rules.)

Answer (score 4):

**TLDR:**

This is an expected behavior. See below why.

**Long answer:**

The object is created only when you use `new` keyword in Java. Every time you use `new` keywork - the object is created. To be very specific, **the creation of the object is the process** that is finished with the [`new` bytecode instruction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.new) finished its execution.

If you read carefully through the JLS `new` bytecode instruction description, there is a note that the object after creation with `new` bytecode instruction requires initialization. This is what you are most likely familiar with - setting fields to their default values, running instance initializing blocks, running constructors etc.

Again, the creation of the object from an application perspective is the process, that involves creation and initialization, etc. What in this example is done, is this:

1. The new `MaliciousSubclass` object is created inside JVM heap memory
2. JVM called object initialization phase - **and it failed**
3. Such an object is going to be ***eventually*** processed by the GC.
4. You get an exception propagated in the StackTrace, therefore the message
5. GC will ***eventually*** clean the object, therefore finalizer is run.

So why `finilize()` is called at all? [There is an answer in the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.1):

> An object o is not finalizable until its constructor has invoked the constructor for Object on o and that invocation has completed successfully (that is, without throwing an exception).

**Thus, because there is an implicit call to `super()` that succeeds in `ResourceClass`, the `MaliciousSubclass` instance is eligible for finilizing**.

So GC, most likely, immediately clean-up the object, and therefore, to adhere to JLS, it had to invoke `finalize()` method.

Answer (score 3):

The idea that the constructor creates an object is a simplification made when describing Java, the *programming language*. However, this quickly falls apart when describing Java, the *virtual machine*.

If one were to inspect the bytecode generated when compiling a Java program, one can see that object creation is actually a two-step process:

1. Instantiate an object of some class X. This effectively creates an empty husk of an X instance with all its fields set to the default values. (All references are `null`, ints are `0`, boolean are `false`, etc.)

   - No programmer-defined logic runs here; it basically just allocates and clears memory for the object and creates a reference to it.
2. A secret special method named `<init>` is called on the object.

   - This is where the constructor logic ends up after compilation.

So basically, the "constructor" doesn't exist to *construct* the instance, but rather to *initialize* it, i.e. taking it from an instance with empty fields to something usable. As such, the constructor is really, from a JVM perspective, just an ordinary* method on the class. It's Java - the programming language - that decides to have the `new X()` syntax do both instantiation and initialization as a single unit, but other languages compiling to the JVM, or indeed certain "arcane sorcery" libraries like Mockito, may choose to treat them as the separate concepts they actually are.

So, to get back to your original question, what happens in your finalization example? Simple. Your `MaliciousSubclass` is successfully *instantiated*, in that it now exists as an object in memory. However, the *initialization* fails. Java - the programming language - will normally not allow you to retrieve the instance associated with a failed constructor call, but in the JVM, it's still a real object that needs to be finalized and GC'd. As such, this uninitialized instance will still have its finalizer invoked.

*) Though, "ordinary" is yet another simplification; methods like `<init>` are actually special-cased by the JVM with various additional rules and restrictions about how they can be used compared to a normal non-constructor method.